# C# - Como dividir un archivo TXT pesado en "n" partes sin perder datos

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un Archivo en formato TXT de peso 1.5 GB deseo partirlo en 5 txt mas pequeños sin afectar la integridad de datos desde C#

Comment: Por favor comparte el código que has utilizado hasta ahora para intentar llegar a la solución de tu problema. Te recomiendo revisar este enlace para que veas tips al preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esta opcion podria ser util

[How to split the large text file(32 GB) using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668829/how-to-split-the-large-text-file32-gb-using-c-sharp)

si revisas al principio plantea usar el `File.ReadAllLines()` pero esto causaria que todas las lineas del archivo se carguen en memoria pudiendo ser un problema si es archivo es grande

La respuesta que le plantea esta interesante

```
using (var lineIterator = File.ReadLines(...).GetEnumerator())
{
}
```

al usar un `iterator` con el `GetEnumerator()` no carga las lineas a memoria directamente sino que puede ir recoriendolas como un cursor, moviendose con el `MoveNext()` para avanzar he ir procesando las lineas que va copiendo a los nuevos archivos.